# SQL What does IF evaluate to for NULL

Tags: sql, null, sql-psm

Hi this is a pretty basic question, but I am not able to find a definitive answer to it.

What does IF evaluate to for NULL in SQL ? What will happen in following code if fieldXYZ were NULL

```
IF fieldXYZ=SomeValue
//do something
ELSE 
//do something else
```

Update:

I have found one result which suggests that NULL can be considered as falsy

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Not sure but I would suggest not relying on "truthy/falsey" evaluations, and just be specific about what you expect to be there.

Comment: In MySQL, you can effectively bypass this problem with the IFNULL() construct:  IFNULL(expr1,expr2) -- If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Comment: In most dialects of SQL, conditions are treated as true, only when they are true.  False and `NULL` values are not true, so the `else` is executed.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah that is my gut feeling as well but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#IF_statements_in_procedural_extensions and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_if_then.htm suggests otherwise

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? There is no `IF` in plain (standard) SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am reluctant to answer my own question, but in absence of any solution, reposting my comment as answer)

Apparently the right way is to consider NULL as falsy.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think your [`if..else`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php) statement is incomplete as you are not defining any expression for your column `fieldXYZ`. Generally, when you write an `if..else` statement, you would want to write an expression that compares your column value with something. You can explicitly check for null values if you want to handle them. Here is a gist of that syntax:

```
--This handles null check explicitly
IF fieldXYZ IS NOT NULL AND fieldXYZ = 'somevalue'
//do something
ELSE 
//do something else
```

Also, if the `fieldXYZ` is passed a `NULL` value in the above statement, then the first condition is not met, so the `else` condition applies immediately in that scenario.Hope this helps!

Comment: I had condensed the condition, but you are right I will write the complete one